# handler.postDelayed is not working(android eclipse)

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am trying to make a delay after playing the set of sounds in mediaplayer so that it won't overlap. i have tried thread.sleep and it worked but the problem is I have a button for sound to stop but because of the thread.sleep, it is not working so i searched and tried for an alternative way in which i can make a delay without locking the UI and i came up with handler.postDelayed but it is not working. is there anyone who can help me solve this problem? thanks in advance.

here is my code:

```
protected void managerOfSound() {
    int size = tempq.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < tempq.size(); i++) {
        String u =tempq.get(i);

    //WHOLE
        if (u.equals("a4")){

            mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.a4);
            mp.start();
            final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    handler.postDelayed(this, 2000);
                }
            };
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    // stuff you wanna delay
  }
}, 2000);
```

The *postDelayed(Runnable r,  long delayMillis )* causes the *Runnable* to be added to the message queue, to be run after the specified amount of time elapses. The runnable will be run on the thread to which this handler is attached ( int htis case the UI thread) . The time-base is *uptimeMillis()*. Time spent in deep sleep will add an additional delay to execution.

Reference  : [Android API documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable,%20long))

Comment: An answer is always stronger if you also explain the solution.

Comment: Yeah, but I thought it was pretty straightforward.

Comment: Well, it doesn't hurt with a short explanation anyway does it?